# Error: Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(DataSnapshot) -> Void'

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, compiler-errors

Here’s my code:

```
func loadData() {
    ref.child(currentUserID!).observe(.childAdded) {
        (snapshot) in
        let snapshotValue = try? snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        if let item = try TableViewModel(id: snapshot.key, likeLabel: self.likeLabel, playLabelString: self.playLabelString, json: snapshotValue) {
            self.items.append(item)
        }            
        self.tableViewModel = self.items.reversed() as [TableViewModel]
    }
}
```

I can’t get my head around the following error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type `(_) throws -> ()` to non-throwing function type`(DataSnapshot) -> Void`

in the following line:

```
ref.child(currentUserID!).observe(.childAdded) {
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue is the following expression:

```
if let item = try TableViewModel(...) {
```

the `try` command indicates your Firebase completion closure *might* throw an error, a situation not expected by the `observe` API you are passing your closure to, hence the compiling error you are having.

Ok, with that out of the way, I belive you had the `try?` operator in mind. If so, try this instead:

```
if let item = try? TableViewModel(...) {
```

or simply:

```
if let item = TableViewModel(...) {
```

if the `TableViewModel` doesn't throw any error at all (i.e. it's just a *failable initializer* instead).

By the way, your `snapshotValue` variable could also use some help:

```
let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was experimenting with the `throws` operator on my `TableViewModel` but I changed them all to `if let` instead and everything seems to be running smooth.